# Are non string values possible in GCM XMPP data bundles?

Tags: android, python, json, google-cloud-messaging

I have a python GCM server (whitelisted) receving messages from my android app just fine, until I include anything other than a string in the data bundle, in which case I only get the string values at the server.

For example my client sends a message with a bundle called data which has a string and an int added like so:

```
data.putString("MSG_ID", ALARM_ID);
data.putInt("AA", 1);
```

And my server reads this and prints this like this:

```
if gcm:
    gcm_json = gcm[0].getData()
    msg = json.loads(gcm_json)
    print msg
```

And the output is:

```
{u'category': u'xxxAPPNAMExxxx', u'from': u'xxxxGCMID', u'data': {u'MSG_ID': u'alarm'}, u'message_id': u'1'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more reading, I found what I must have missed on the first few read throughs:

> [public void send (String to, String msgId, Bundle data)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#send%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)
>
> Send an upstream ("device to cloud") message. You can only use the
>   upstream feature if your GCM implementation uses the XMPP-based Cloud
>   Connection Server. The message will be queued if we don't have an
>   active connection for the max interval.
>
> Parameters to string identifying the receiver of the message. For GCM
>   project IDs the value is SENDER_ID@gcm.googleapis.com. The SENDER_ID
>   should be one of the sender IDs used in register(). msgId ID of the
>   message. This is generated by the application. It must be unique for
>   each message. This allows error callbacks and debugging.
>   data  key/value pairs to be sent. Values must be String—any other type
>   will be ignored.

So **TLDR; Only strings allowed.**